# Incorrect Route getting picked up and ActionLink is generating wrong hyperlink

Tags: asp.net-mvc-routing

I am new to ASP.NET MVC3.

I have configured some routes in Global.asax, against which I am generating some hyperlinks using @Html.ActionLink helper method.

All of the links are getting correctly rendered except the top one in the below code:

**Global.asax**

```
routes.MapRoute(
    null,
    "Section/{Page}/{SubPage}/{DetailPageName}",
    new { controller = "Base" }
    );

routes.MapRoute(
    null,
    "Section/{Page}/{SubPage}",
    new { controller = "Base", action = "SubPage" }
    );

routes.MapRoute(
    null,
    "Section/{Page}",
    new { controller ="Base", action="LandingPage"}
    );

routes.MapRoute(
    "Default", // Route name
    "{controller}/{action}", // URL with parameters
    new { controller = "Base", action = "Index" } // Parameter defaults
    );
```

**ActionLink code**

```
@Html.ActionLink(@subPages.LinkedPageName, "DetailPage",
    new {
        Controller = "Base",
        Page = @ViewBag.PageName,
        SubPage = @Model.SubPageName,
        DetailPageName = subPages.LinkedPageName
    })
```

The above should pick the top route i.e.:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    null,
    "Section/{Page}/{SubPage}/{DetailPageName}",
    new { controller = "Base" }
    );
```

But it is picking the default route!

Comment: I noticed there is no `action` defined in your first route.

Answer (score 2):

In this route definition:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    null,
    "Section/{Page}/{SubPage}/{DetailPageName}",
    new { controller = "Base" }
    );
```

The following conditions must be satisfied in order for the route to match:

1. If there is a `controller` parameter passed into `ActionLink` then its value must be `Base`
2. The `Page` parameter must be specified and must be non-empty because it has no default value
3. The `SubPage` parameter must be specified and must be non-empty because it has no default value
4. The `DetailPageName` parameter must be specified and must be non-empty because it has no default value

So in this call to `ActionLink`:

```
@Html.ActionLink(@subPages.LinkedPageName, "DetailPage",
    new {
        Controller = "Base",
        Page = @ViewBag.PageName,
        SubPage = @Model.SubPageName,
        DetailPageName = subPages.LinkedPageName
    })
```

Condition #1 is clearly satisfied. But conditions #2, #3, and #4 might not be satisfied because their values might be null.

And because you state that the route that ends up matching is the default route, I suspect that the `Page` parameter is null or empty. that is, `@ViewBag.PageName` is returning a null or empty value.

Check in your code (perhaps in the debugger or print it out in the view) to see whether the `PageName` property has a value.